# How to remove only show caption option from the table properties in tinymce v5.8.2 angular

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

Im using tinymce editor v.5.8.2 and in tinymce, I would like to remove show caption option from the table properties. Below is the image of list of table properties.

[image: Table properties]

I have found one way using advtable plugin which is a paid plugin.
Is there anything I can do without installing new plugins or only opensource plugins.

Also, there is option table_appearance_options, if set to false it is removing few other properties among the table properties.

I would like to remove only show captions.

Thanks in advance